# postgresql connection failing intermittently (Windows)

Tags: bash, powershell, php, postgresql

**Setup:** PostgreSQL on Windows 10; PHP7 running a Symfony3 app (a stub) either in PowerShell or via Bash on Windows (WSL). I have no antivirus software or firewall other than Windows' own.

**Error:** 1 out of 10 times I perform a click in the web app, the symfony debugger will show:

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] server closed the connection unexpectedly
>
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ConnectionException, 2 linked Exceptions: PDOException » PDOException »

In the PostgreSQL server logs it will say:

> 2017-03-15 02:26:58 CST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
>
> 2017-03-15 02:27:04 CST LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

**Attempts:** I have already configured the windows firewall to allow postgresql.exe through on port 5432. I have tried running the php7 server from both Powershell and from Bash on Windows, but with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not *really* an answer but it sort of works. In the coming Windows Creators update, WSL actually allows installing and running the PostgreSQL server within the same environment. This way no socket connection is necessary.

I've not seen the error since.